# How to convert callbacks to Rx.Observable?

Tags: system.reactive

If an external library offers only to register a callback instead of an event, what is the best way to create an `Observable` from it?

If it where an event I could use `Observable.FromEventPattern`  but in this case the only idea I have is to use a `Subject`and queue events in it on each callback.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `Observable.Create`. Get to know him well. He is your friend in Rx. While making friends with `Observable.Create`, break off your relationship with `Subject`, no good will come from that relationship ;-)

Comment: I know you always tell me :-) I had a situation though short ago where I had to pass whole delegate objects with callbacks to an iOS Api, there Subject was a good solution.

Comment: Lol, i do don't. But in the scenario you describe, sounds perfect for Obs.Create and awful for subjects! #dogmatic

Comment: Even Paul Betts agreed that there it's ok ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Observable.Create`.](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableCreate) Here's an example:

```
void Main()
{
    var target = new SampleCallbacker();
    var actionB = new Action<int>(i => Console.WriteLine($"{i} * {i} = {i * i}."));
    target.Register(actionB);

    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
    {
        var action = new Action<int>(i => observer.OnNext(i));
        target.Register(action);
        return () => target.Unregister(action);
    });

    var subscription = observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine($"From observable: {i} was fired."));

    target.Fire(1);
    target.Fire(2);
    target.Fire(3);
    Console.WriteLine("Unsusbscribing observable...");
    subscription.Dispose();
    target.Fire(4);
    target.Fire(5);
}

class SampleCallbacker
{
    private List<Action<int>> _actions = new List<System.Action<int>>();
    public void Register(Action<int> action)
    {
        _actions.Add(action);
    }

    public void Unregister(Action<int> action)
    {
        while (_actions.Remove(action))
        {} //loop remove
    }

    public void Fire(int i)
    {
        foreach (var action in _actions)
        {
            action(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. But this will subscribe to the event mutiple times, for each subscriber of the Observable, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want to share a subscription, add `.Publish().RefCount()` after the `Create` call.